# Prettier installed globally but command not found

Tags: node.js

I was trying to learn CLI tools and following the steps on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Understanding_client-side_tools/Command_line#Installing_Prettier).

And below is the problem I met.

```
$ npm install --global prettier
C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\prettier -> 
C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prettier\bin-prettier.js
+ prettier@2.1.2
added 1 package from 1 contributor in 0.718s
```

I installed Prettier globally, and seems it succeeded.
But as I tried to run the command, it showed

```
$ prettier
C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
```

I found this solution from google [Solution](https://medium.com/@jagatjyoti.1si13cs040/npm-g-install-npm-package-not-working-as-desired-why-why-why-19795abf0b59#a1dd)

And then I found that my path was different from his

```
$ npm bin -g
C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

It seems my Node was installed for only one user?
But I can't figure out what's the exact problem.
Could anyone show me a way?

I am lost...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check if Node is accessible for you.

`node -v` should show some version number

Regarding the command not found.

This happens in a Windows machine. You need to add the npm path in Environment variables `path`

The path value will be `C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm`

- Right click This PC
- Properties Advanced system settings -> Advacnced
  tab -> Environment variables
- Under User variables Click path, then
  click Edit Append the path value (sample I pasted above.)

Now exit all command prompt windows and try your commands

Comment: I tried to add the value in my environment variable Path, but it's already there. And I closed my GitBash tried to try it again. It still can't work :(

Comment: What confuses me is this line `C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node` are you sure your path is correct? Did you combine 2 paths together?

Comment: Thank you! I deleted the npm and npm-cache in my Roaming and reinstall Node again, it works now! I think the reason for this is that I reinstall the node.js last week and don't know why it didn't overwrite the path but installed inside it.

Answer (score 19):

It helped for me let's try:

```
npm install -g prettier
```

Answer (score 1):

install with yarn solved the problem

```
yarn global add prettier
```